# Loop through jQuery plugin options

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, plugins, contextmenu

I'm not sure how to do this, i thought i was doing it right, but apparently not. In the 2nd code block you'll see a console.log() call and the way i *thought* you would loop through all the `item`s but that isn't working. How would I do this? Also, this is a work in progress hence all the commented code, but this is the main part!

Thanks in advance!

So, i have this for my jQuery plugin call:

```
$('p').contextMenu({
                item:{
                    name:'Back',
                    action:function(){
                        alert('Back!');
                    },
                    icon:'http://cdn.iconfinder.net/data/icons/crystalproject/16x16/actions/agt_back.png'
                },
                item:{
                    name:'Forward',
                    action:function(){
                        alert('Forward!');
                    },
                    icon:'http://cdn.iconfinder.net/data/icons/crystalproject/16x16/actions/agt_forward.png'
                }
            });
```

And here is my actual jQuery plugin code:

```
(function($){
                $.fn.extend({ 
                    //plugin name - animatemenu
                    contextMenu: function(menuitems,options) {
                        if(!options){options == null;}
                        //Settings list and the default values
                        var defaults = {
                        };

                        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

                        return this.each(function() {
                            var o =options;

                            //Assign current element to variable, in this case is UL element
                            var $obj = $(this);             

                            $obj.mousedown(function(event) {
                                switch (event.which) {
                                    case 1: //Left
                                    //alert('Left mouse button pressed');
                                    break;
                                    case 2: //Middle
                                    //alert('Middle mouse button pressed');
                                    break;
                                    case 3: //Right
                                    //menuitems.item.action();
                                    for(x in menuitems){
                                        console.log(menuitems.item[x])
                                    }
                                    break;
                                    default: //Unknown

                                }
                            });

                        });
                    }
                });
            })(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your menuitems object can only have one `item` property and it's getting overwritten in your declaration. Make menuitems an array instead:

```
$('p').contextMenu([
    {
        name:'Back',
        action:function(){
            alert('Back!');
        },
        icon:'http://cdn.iconfinder.net/data/icons/crystalproject/16x16/actions/agt_back.png'
    }, 
    {
        name:'Forward',
        action:function(){
            alert('Forward!');
        },
        icon:'http://cdn.iconfinder.net/data/icons/crystalproject/16x16/actions/agt_forward.png'
    }
]);
```

If you think it needs to be simplified a bit for the devs you're referring to, perhaps just define the items as a variable first.

```
var items = [ {name: 'Forward'}, {name: 'Back'} ];
$('p').contextMenu(items);
```

Then you can access both items the way you originally intended:

```
var len = menuitems.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++;){
    console.log(menuitems[i]);
}
```

Just as a side note, I've changed your `for in` loop to a regular `for`. The `for in` loop is really inefficient and should be avoided. (My replacement loop could be written more efficiently as well, but then the syntax starts to look strange and your comment seems to indicate that the devs you work with might get a little confused (no disrespect intended there)).

Comment: That only returns 1 object tho, and it's only returning the last one, "item:'Forward'". Any ideas why?

Comment: he means `console.log(menuitems[x]);` within the `for (x in menuitems)` block.

Comment: It's only returning one item because you're overwriting the `item` property of your menuitems object. If you define items as an array, you might find it easier to get what you're looking for, i.e. `{ items: [{ name: 'Back'}, {name: 'Forward'}]}`

Comment: Thanks, I'll try the array thing. Since this is for other devs, you think this would be simple enough that way or can you think of a better syntax? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I've adjusted my answer to reflect these comments.

Comment: Awesome testing out your first example. I think it's hard at all actually. If it works ill mark it as correct. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Also, could you show me how to write that the most efficient way you know? They wont be getting into the source code. They just need the end code to be simple as they are designers...

Comment: To write the loop more efficiently, you just need to reduce the number of operations in each iteration. `for (var i = 0; i < len; i++;)` is four operations, three of which will run on each iteration. If the order of the menu items is unimportant, you can use a reverse loop to start at the end and cut down the number of operations. `for (var i = menuitems.length; i--;)` is still four operations (1. `menuitems.length` property lookup, 2. `i = menuitems.length`, 3. `i--`, 4. comparing `i--` to true), but only the two involving `i--` are repeated on each iteration.

Comment: I'm having an issue now tho, and with the first `for` loop. The `for in` seems to work, but not these `for` loops. It's saying "Cannot read property 'action' of undefined" when i click on one of the items...? do you know why?